# Angular2 location.back() page reloads?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services

I am in need to give a Go-Back button for this I am using location services as:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

backclicked(): void
{
    console.log("back clicked.");
    this.location.back();
} 

<a id="redirect-link" (click)="backclicked();" style="padding:8px 15px;" >
```

Issue is this that location.back() is working but with page load. So is their a way where it can be achieved without page load ?. Any help please ?

Comment: I came across this issue today, what I noticed was the router.navigate in the parent page is using the parameter repaceUrl=true, it worked fine when I removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built in location service in angular 2 which having "Back" api.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';


@Component({ directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] })
@RouteConfig([
    {...},
])
class AppCmp {
    constructor(private _location: Location) {
    }
    backClicked() {
        this._location.back();
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is the same as what in question. The issue is about reloading, as pointed in the question location.back() reloads the page instead of going back without reloading